# Sql Server equivalent of a COUNTIF aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm building a query with a `GROUP BY` clause that needs the ability to count records based only on a certain condition (e.g. count only records where a certain column value is equal to 1).

```
SELECT  UID, 
        COUNT(UID) AS TotalRecords, 
        SUM(ContractDollars) AS ContractDollars,
        (COUNTIF(MyColumn, 1) / COUNT(UID) * 100) -- Get the average of all records that are 1
FROM    dbo.AD_CurrentView
GROUP BY UID
HAVING  SUM(ContractDollars) >= 500000
```

The `COUNTIF()` line obviously fails since there is no native SQL function called `COUNTIF`, but the idea here is to determine the percentage of all rows that have the value '1' for MyColumn.

Any thoughts on how to properly implement this in a MS SQL 2005 environment?

Answer (score 407, accepted):

You could use a `SUM` (not `COUNT`!) combined with a `CASE` statement, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN myColumn=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM AD_CurrentView
```

Note: in my own test `NULL`s were not an issue, though this can be environment dependent. You could handle nulls such as:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(myColumn,0)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM AD_CurrentView
```

Comment: (I know the OP asked about MS SQL, but just a tiny comment for SQLite users doing the same thing) SQLite has no `ISNULL`, instead you can do `CASE WHEN myColumn IS NULL`, or use `ifnull` ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/799406/1861346 )

Comment: can you explain why `sum` instead of `count`?

Comment: **Note**: if the aggregate function receives no record at all, `SUM()` will return NULL, whereas `COUNT` will return 0. If you need to have an integer result, you should use `COALESCE(SUM(...), 0)`. For example `SELECT SUM(1) FROM any_table WHERE 1 = 0` will not return an integer.

Answer (score 58):

I usually do what Josh recommended, but brainstormed and tested a slightly hokey alternative that I felt like sharing.

You can take advantage of the fact that COUNT(ColumnName) doesn't count NULLs, and use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(0, myColumn))
FROM AD_CurrentView
```

NULLIF - returns NULL if the two passed in values are the same.

Advantage: Expresses your intent to COUNT rows instead of having the SUM() notation.
Disadvantage: Not as clear how it is working ("magic" is usually bad).

Comment: This solution can gives a different answers than the sum when a group only contains nulls it result in 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Old post, but thanks this helped.  I extended the magic and got around the "only nulls" problem by adding `ISNULL` as follows: `SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(0, ISNULL(myColumn, 0)))`.  Wait, that just looks ugly...

Comment: Would be perfect if there was a NULLIFNOT function

Answer (score 29):

I would use this syntax. It achives the same as Josh and Chris's suggestions, but with the advantage it is ANSI complient and not tied to a particular database vendor.

```
select count(case when myColumn = 1 then 1 else null end)
from   AD_CurrentView
```

Comment: Chris's answer is Stndard SQL compliant (hint: `NULLIF` is included Standard SQL-92). Josh's answer can be easily transformed into Standard SQL by replacing `isnull` with `COALESCE`.

Comment: I actually like this answer best, because it gets the idea of "counting rows" that Chris was showing, but is more extensible, since you can use any comparison operator; not just `=`.  I'm using it for "count the number of responses >=2".

Comment: `else null` can be omitted

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
SELECT id, COUNT(IF status=42 THEN 1 ENDIF) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY table
```

Shorter than `CASE` :)

Works because `COUNT()` doesn't count null values, and `IF`/`CASE` return null when condition is not met and there is no `ELSE`.

I think it's better than using `SUM()`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to Josh's answer,

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN myColumn=1 THEN AD_CurrentView.PrimaryKeyColumn ELSE NULL END)
FROM AD_CurrentView
```

Worked well for me (in SQL Server 2012) without changing the 'count' to a 'sum' and the same logic is portable to other 'conditional aggregates'.  E.g., summing based on a condition:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN myColumn=1 THEN AD_CurrentView.NumberColumn ELSE 0 END)
FROM AD_CurrentView
```

Answer (score 3):

It's 2022 and latest SQL Server still doesn't have `COUNTIF` (along with regex!). Here's what I use:

```sql
-- Count if MyColumn = 42
SELECT SUM(IIF(MyColumn = 42, 1, 0))
FROM MyTable
```

`IIF` is a shortcut for `CASE WHEN MyColumn = 42 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`.

Comment: Just to note - the difference between IIF and CASE is that IIF will return null if no records meet the criteria, whereas CASE (and also just COUNT()) will return 0

Answer (score 2):

Not product-specific, but the SQL standard provides

```sql
SELECT COUNT() FILTER WHERE <condition-1>,
       COUNT() FILTER WHERE <condition-2>, ...
  FROM ...
```

for this purpose.  Or something that closely resembles it, I don't know off the top of my hat.

And of course vendors will prefer to stick with their proprietary solutions.

Comment: I had never heard of this before, so I looked it up.  According to http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter the only major DBMS that actually offers the `FILTER` clause is PostgreSQL, but it is emulated by `CASE` in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM AD_CurrentView
WHERE myColumn=1
```

Comment: Because he needs a lot more than just the count.  He's trying to get rowcount of a part of a group, and then an aggregate of the whole group, which you can't do with a WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use COUNTIF() in my case as part of my SELECT columns AND to mimic a % of the number of times each item appeared in my results.

So I used this...

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, ... ETC
       (1 / SELECT a.vcount 
            FROM (SELECT vm2.visit_id, count(*) AS vcount 
                  FROM dbo.visitmanifests AS vm2 
                  WHERE vm2.inactive = 0 AND vm2.visit_id = vm.Visit_ID 
                  GROUP BY vm2.visit_id) AS a)) AS [No of Visits],
       COL xyz
FROM etc etc
```

Of course you will need to format the result according to your display requirements.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(IF(myColumn = 1,COUNT(DISTINCT NumberColumn),NULL),0) column1,
COALESCE(CASE WHEN myColumn = 1 THEN COUNT(DISTINCT NumberColumn) ELSE NULL END,0) AS column2
FROM AD_CurrentView
```