# Replace Default Null Values Returned From Left Outer Join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 query that returns data from three tables using a left outer join.  Many times, there is no data in the second and third tables and so I get a null which I think is the default for left outer join.  Is there a way to replace the default values in the select statement?  I have a workaround in that I can select into a table variable but it feels a little dirty.

```
SELECT iar.Description, iai.Quantity, iai.Quantity * rpl.RegularPrice as 'Retail', 
iar.Compliance FROM InventoryAdjustmentReason iar
LEFT OUTER JOIN InventoryAdjustmentItem iai  on (iar.Id = iai.InventoryAdjustmentReasonId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Item i on (i.Id = iai.ItemId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReportPriceLookup rpl on (rpl.SkuNumber = i.SkuNo)
WHERE iar.StoreUse = 'yes'
```

I would like the Quantity and RegularPrice to default to zero if possible.

Comment: **Note:** Some of the answers on this post deal with databases other than MSFT sql-server, causing this answer to show up on search results pages for those other contexts as well.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799375/sqlite-equivalent-to-isnull-nvl-ifnull-or-coalesce

Answer (score 165, accepted):

That's as easy as

```
IsNull(FieldName, 0)
```

Or more completely:

```
SELECT iar.Description, 
  ISNULL(iai.Quantity,0) as Quantity, 
  ISNULL(iai.Quantity * rpl.RegularPrice,0) as 'Retail', 
  iar.Compliance 
FROM InventoryAdjustmentReason iar
LEFT OUTER JOIN InventoryAdjustmentItem iai  on (iar.Id = iai.InventoryAdjustmentReasonId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Item i on (i.Id = iai.ItemId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ReportPriceLookup rpl on (rpl.SkuNumber = i.SkuNo)
WHERE iar.StoreUse = 'yes'
```

Comment: I knew it had to be easy but for some reason, I was blocked on how to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: If it is MySQL, IsNull should be replaced with 'IFNULL'. Thanks.

Comment: In PostgreSQL, it seems to be ["COALESCE"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html). For MySQL, the manual page is here: ["IFNULL"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html). Not sure about the standard.

Comment: In DB2 the answer seems to be 'switch databases'.

Comment: For SQLite, it will be `IFNULL`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) also works in MySQL

Answer (score 27):

In case of `MySQL` or `SQLite` the correct keyword is **`IFNULL`** (not `ISNULL`).

```
 SELECT iar.Description, 
      IFNULL(iai.Quantity,0) as Quantity, 
      IFNULL(iai.Quantity * rpl.RegularPrice,0) as 'Retail', 
      iar.Compliance 
    FROM InventoryAdjustmentReason iar
    LEFT OUTER JOIN InventoryAdjustmentItem iai  on (iar.Id = iai.InventoryAdjustmentReasonId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Item i on (i.Id = iai.ItemId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReportPriceLookup rpl on (rpl.SkuNumber = i.SkuNo)
WHERE iar.StoreUse = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 14):

## MySQL

```
COALESCE(field, 'default')
```

For example:

```
  SELECT
    t.id,
    COALESCE(d.field, 'default')
  FROM
     test t
  LEFT JOIN
     detail d ON t.id = d.item
```

Also, you can use multiple columns to check their `NULL` by [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.
For example:

```
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 1, NULL);
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(0, 1, NULL);
        -> 0
mysql> SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, NULL);
        -> NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

For **Oracle** you can use:

`NVL(columnName,deafultValue)` :- NVL is used to convert a null value to a default value in the query output. eg. If you want to replace null values with 'NA' then use something like this.

`SELECT NVL(columnName,'NA') FROM tableName`