# How to make =NULL work in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

Given the following table:

```
Table: Comedians
=================

Id    First    Middle    Last
---  -------  --------  -------
 1     Bob      NULL     Sagat
 2    Jerry     Kal      Seinfeld
```

I want to make the following prepared query:

```
SELECT * FROM Comedians WHERE Middle=?
```

work for all cases. It currently does not work for the case where I pass NULL via `sqlite3_bind_null`. I realize that the query to actually search for NULL values uses `IS NULL`, but that would mean that I cannot use the prepared query for all cases. I would actually have to change the query depending on the input, which largely defeats the purpose of the prepared query. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: How would a user search for a comedian without a middle name?

Comment: @Mithrandir This isnt a user facing function, it is for internal use. Essentially, I pass a pointer (char*) to the function. If the pointer is NULL I use  `sqlite3_bind_null` but if it is the string 'NULL' I use the string function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`IS` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#isisnot) instead of `=`.

```
SELECT * FROM Comedians WHERE Middle IS ?
```

Comment: @dotje: In PostgreSQL you can use `a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b`. Slightly more expensive than `a = b`.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing matches `= NULL`.  The only way to check that is with `IS NULL`.

You can do a variety of things, but the straight forward one is...

```
WHERE
  middle = ?
  OR (middle IS NULL and ? IS NULL)
```

If there is a value you know NEVER appears, you can change that to...

```
WHERE
  COALESCE(middle, '-') = COALESCE(?, '-')
```

But you need a value that literally *NEVER* appears.  Also, it obfuscates the use of indexes, but the `OR` version can often suck as well (I don't know how well SQLite treats it).

All things equal, I recommend the first version.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is not a value, but an attribute of a field.  Instead use

```
SELECT * FROM Comedians WHERE Middle IS NULL
```

Comment: this isnt a generic solution since it doesnt allow me to test equality with something other than null

Comment: @chacham15:  There is no generic solution using NULL, since it is not a value.  Perhaps you should use a [sentinel value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want match everything on NULL

```
SELECT * FROM Comedians WHERE Middle=IfNull(?, Middle)
```

if want match none on NULL

```
SELECT * FROM Comedians WHERE Middle=IfNull(?, 'DUMMY'+Middle)
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/799406/30225