# SQLite null value - treat as zero in .NET calculations

Tags: .net, sqlite, null, zero

What is the most effective way to use null value in SQLite database treated as zero value in .NET calculations? I use Entity Framework.

Let's say I have:

```
Dim result as Double
result = e_employee_salary * e_index
```

where e_employee_salary and e_index and fields in the SQLite database but one or both of them can be null and in that case I want to treat them as zero value in the above calculation.

I'm looking the **most effective way** to do that since these calculations appear in many property getters all over and are called with high frequencies.

Comment: Any reason why the null value couldn't be trapped from the query/sql perspective?  Assuming isnull is a SQLite function:      
     
isnull(column_name, 0) will always return 0 (integer) when it is null.     
  
isnull(column_name, '0') will always return '0' (string) when column is null.   Just a suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799375/sqlite-equivalent-to-isnull-nvl-ifnull-or-coalesce

Comment: I am using Entity Framework and not directly defining sql queries. I do LINQ to Entities instead to read data.

Answer (score 2):

You may have two approaches: using programming language, as @Claudio or using SQLite query:

```
 SELECT IFNULL(e_employee_salary, 0.0), IFNULL(e_index, 0.0), ... FROM ...
```

This way you will always get non-null values from database.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something on your question, but I'd say you could use

```
If(e_employee_salary, 0) * If(e_index, 0) // VB

(e_employee_salary ?? 0) * (e_index ?? 0) // C#
```

Comment: I'm getting a design-time error: The '?' character cannot be used here. Is that C# (I use VB.NET). Can you refer to some MSDN documentation maybe?

Comment: @user2143213: sorry. Added VB version