# Android "null" from SUM

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query that takes data from 2 tables.
It works, but the two SUMs return NULL if there are no values.
How can I get zero instead?

```
SELECT SUM(g.field1), 
       SUM(g.field2), 
       c._id, 
       c.field_1, 
       c.field_3 
  FROM Table1 g 
  JOIN Tabel2 c 
 WHERE ( c.field_1 = g.field5 )
```

Comment: What do you want to get instead?

Comment: any Errors? What say LogCat?

Comment: Now if `SUM (g.field1), SUM (g.field2)` is 0 I get "null" instead I would get equally the result. I hope I explained

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799375/sqlite-equivalent-to-isnull-nvl-ifnull-or-coalesce

Comment: no error but I get null as the result of the query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The SUM functions returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

To get a return value of 0 even if there are no input values, just replace SUM with the [TOTAL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) function:

```sql
SELECT TOTAL(g.field1), 
       TOTAL(g.field2), 
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFNULL statement on your fields,

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799375/sqlite-equivalent-to-isnull-nvl-ifnull-or-coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

What about SQlite **coalesce()** ?

The coalesce() function returns a copy of its first non-NULL argument, or NULL if all arguments are NULL. Coalesce() must have at least 2 arguments.

In your case for every field you can use:

```
coalesce(c.field_X,0)
```

and the query will return 0 if c.field_X is NULL.

Please see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Comment: Ok I use `coalesce ()`, so if `(c.field_1 = g.field5)` is null, I would still run the query `SELECT c._id, c.field_1, c.field_3 FROM Tabel2 c`
How can I?

Comment: I'm not following you, can you rephrase? How can (c.field_1 = g.field5) be null? It'd be either true or false, not NULL. If you want to check for equality including NULL check you can explode the IF condition to explicitely handle NULL vals.

Comment: Si può essere perché nella clausola WHERE confronta `g.field5` con `c.field_1`, quindi se `c.field_1` è vuoto la query non dà risultati. A quel punto vorrei far eseguire solo `SELECT c._id, c.field_1, c.field_3 FROM Tabel2 c`

Comment: Let's keep with English for the others (I'm Italian as well) but The others are not :)

The CONDITION can't be null (but the terms can as you explained). You basically want to ignore the condition if one of the value is null. 

You can modify the WHERE like this:


WHERE (c.field_1 IS NULL OR  g.field5 IS NULL OR c.field_1 = g.field5)

Comment: Unfortunately, even so, if c.field_1, returns null. I could replace it with a subquery? but at that point as I run the cursor?