# filtering inside COUNT in sql server

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Equivalent of COUNTIF()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-equivalent-of-countif)

Can I incorporate some kind of filtering mechanism inside COUNT itself, which I dont want to use in WHERE or JOINs of the query (since it is a part of large query in which there are other columns too which I dont want to get affected by where and join conditions).

For example I can use case inside SUM

```
SUM(CASE WHEN work_status IN ('V','L') THEN shift_total_hours ELSE 0 END),
```

Can I do something like this in COUNT too, so that I would get count for particular rows only

something like this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN work_status IN ('V','L') THEN <should come in count> ELSE <exclude from count> END)
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can just use

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN work_status IN ('V','L') THEN 1 END)
```

For rows not matching the specified condition the `CASE` expression returns `NULL` and `COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values

Comment: +1. Put another way, if the ELSE branch is left out, `ELSE NULL` is implied.

Answer (score 9):

This should do what you want:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN work_status IN ('V','L') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Although it is using the SUM aggregate function, it is effectively a conditional count because for each row, you are adding either 1 or 0 to the sum.

Comment: Doesn't work with DISTINCT though.