# SQL: Count duplicate records based on condition

Tags: sql

The below is a **small section** of a query that I need help with. This section produces a count of records where both the EmailAddress and DateOfBirth are duplicated.

The commented out line should produce a count of records where the EmailAddress is duplicated but the DateOfBirth differs. i.e. Identify users who share an email address (assuming two users would have different date of births).

```
SELECT     
u.EmailAddress,
u.DateOfBirth,
COUNT(*) over (partition by u.EmailAddress, DateOfBirth) AS EmailAndDoBDup,

--COUNT(*) where EmailAddress is duplicate but DateOfBirth is unique (in the aggregated results)

FROM [User] AS u
```

Thanks

Comment: it's better to mention or tag the `RDBMS` also, it's MySQL, MS SQL Server, or etc?

Comment: use a combination of SUM and CASE:   SUM(CASE WHEN SomeCondition=True THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Equivalent of COUNTIF()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-equivalent-of-countif)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a subquery.  I don't think there is a way to do this with a single window function:

```
SELECT u.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth,
       EmailAndDoBDup,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EmailAndDoBDup = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress) as YourCol
FROM (SELECT u.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER (partition by u.EmailAddress, DateOfBirth) as EmailAndDoBDup
      FROM [User] u
     ) u;
```

EDIT:

If you wanted one row per email address and DOB, you can phrase this as an aggregation query:

```
SELECT u.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth, COUNT(*) as EmailAndDoBDup,
       SUM(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY EmailAddress) as YourCol
FROM [User] u
GROUP BY u.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth;
```

This doesn't require the subquery, but it might not fit into your more complex query.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing it in the SELECT section, I would left outer join the two sets, like:

```
LEFT OUTER join
(SELECT     
    EmailAddress,
    DateOfBirth
FROM
    USER
GROUP BY
    EmailAddress,
    DateOfBirth
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT ID) > 1) dupEmailDOB
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT     
    EmailAddress
FROM
    USER
GROUP BY
    EmailAddress
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT DateOfBirth) > 1) emailMultipleDOBs
```

because it's easier to maintain if you need to add additional criteria