# Excel COUNTIFS equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

This may seem silly, but what is the countifs equivalent in sql server? I have 2 columns, and want to count where both repeat. So if column 1 is date and there are 2 dates of 1/1/2016 and column 2 is name and there are 2 names of Bill, how would I show this as a 3rd column called count, which would produce the number 2 as the result?

Comment: Can you please post sone example input data and example output data?

Comment: Have you tried a GROUP BY with any success?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server equivalent of a COUNTIF aggregate function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-server-equivalent-of-a-countif-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 4):

if you are using sql server 2005 + then you can use the OVER() clause with COUNT
[**Over Clause info**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.90).aspx)

```
select 
    date,
    name,
    count(*) over (partition by date, name) cnt
from 
    table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ColumDate, ColumName, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumDate, ColumName
```