# SQL Count of Column value and its a subColumn

Tags: sql, group-by, db2

I have A Table in DB2 Database such as below:

```
StatusCode | IsResolved | IsAssigned
ABC        |    Y       |    
ABC        |    N       |
ABC        |            |    
ADEF       |    Y       |    
ADEF       |            |    Y
```

I want to get data in the way such as:

```
StatusCode |Count of Status Code| Count of Resolved with value Y| Count of Assigned With value Y
ABC        |         3          |            1                  |          0
ADEF       |         2          |            1                  |          1
```

I am able to get count of Status Code by using `groupBy` but I am not sure how to fetch data of count of resolved and assigned in the same query.

```
Query: select statusCode,count(statusCode) from table group by statusCode
```

Can anyone help me in how to fetch the resolved and Assigned count?

Issue Solution: Christian and JPW: Solution was to Use sum(case IsResolved when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag the question with the database you are really using.

Comment: In the given data [per given as text vs a DML INSERT], is each *invisible* value suppose to be the empty-string or the NULL value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
 select statusCode, count(statusCode),
        sum(case IsResolved when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case IsAssigned when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) 
 from table
 group by statusCode
```

Comment: Just a FollowUp Question can we also Use Case to get Value such as : Count where isResolved!='y' and IsAssigned !='Y'

Comment: @JashanPreet - yes

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the result you want is to use *conditional aggregation* (where you use a predicate to determine how to aggregate data) like this:

```
select 
  StatusCode, 
  count(*) as "Count of Status Code",
  sum(case when IsResolved = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as "Count of Resolved with value Y",
  sum(case when IsAssigned = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as "Count of Assigned With value Y"
from your_table
group by StatusCode;
```

The *case expression* construct (`case ... when ... then .. end`) is part of the ANSI SQL standard, so this should work in any compliant database.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using SUM() and CASE

```
SELECT 
statusCode,
COUNT(statusCode)
,SUM(CASE WHEN IsResolved='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Resolved
,SUM(CASE WHEN IsAssigned='Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Assigned
FROM [Questions] GROUP BY statusCode
```

Here is a related question: [Sql Server equivalent of a COUNTIF aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-server-equivalent-of-a-countif-aggregate-function)

Comment: There are two answers that are functionally the same and more correct given the requirements that were posted over a half hour ago -- why did you post this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the prior answers used the SUM aggregate because the value of the *missing* values was unknown.  If the *missing* values are the NULL value, then each could have been coded as the COUNT with the same effect as the SUM.

And if the *missing* values from the "I have a table" given in the OP are the NULL value, **and** if [effectively the data meets or actually there exists] a CHECK constraint for the **is**ColumnNames of `IN ('Y','N')`, then similar to the other answers, but performing a COUNT and using NULLIF as a simplified/special-case effect of the CASE expression:

```
 select
   statuscode                    as "StatusCode"
 , count(*)                      as "Count of Status Code"
 , count(nullif(isResolved,'N')) as "Count of Resolved with value Y"
 , count(nullif(isAssigned,'N')) as "Count of Assigned with value Y"
 from so39705143    
 group by statuscode
 order by statuscode
```