# How to Count IF a date from a column is from previous month

Tags: t-sql, count, countif

For our mortgage loans, we keep track of 'Lock Date'. I want to write an expression that counts the number of Lock Dates that occurred in the Previous Month (we have a token in my sql system for previous month start, previous month end, or just previous month name)

This is as far as I've gotten, but I keep getting an error:

```
COUNT(LockDate)
CASE WHEN LockDate BETWEEN @prevmonthstart AND @prevmonthend
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql Server equivalent of a COUNTIF aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-server-equivalent-of-a-countif-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 2):

Change your expression to this:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN LockDate BETWEEN @prevmonthstart AND @prevmonthend THEN LockDate ELSE NULL END)
```

and you should get the result you are looking for. Another way to accomplish the same thing is to use SUM with a conditional expression:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN LockDate BETWEEN @prevmonthstart AND @prevmonthend THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

which might be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a perform-ant option would be to put this condition in the where clause and simply do a COUNT(*) in the SELECT.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE LockDate BETWEEN @prevmonthstart AND @prevmonthend
```