# Postgresql select items and sum of each of their statuses

Tags: postgresql

I am fed up with creating sql query to database table, which contains, let's say just three columns - id, title and status. What I need is write a select which shows total of all titles and their each and every status sum. Would appreciate any ideas.

Database:

| ID | Title | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Title A | Done |
| 2 | Title B | Done |
| 3 | Title A | Rejected |
| 4 | Title B | Done |
| 5 | Title A | Done |
| 6 | Title B | Done |
| 7 | Title A | Rejected |
| 8 | Title B | Done |

What I need is:

| Title | Done | Rejected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title A | 6 | 2 |
| Title B | 8 | 0 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want SO to write the SQL for you, because you are fed up with doing it?

Comment: Well, as I wrote before (in case you are blind), I "Would appreciate any ideas". So, SO, so if anyone knows what functions or methoss on postgres that would help, I would be thankful.

Comment: Well I sure am motivated to help now. I was partially asking if what was needed was SQL. Q2, is it always just those 2 statuses, I mean is it a fixed number?

Comment: It will be fixes number of statuses. For now 5. I am sure that I would construct some how the query I need if someone would put me on the right path. I mean, maybe I should look at COUNT, SUM, or some inner joins between same table - I've been trying for 4 hours with no luck. Some people gives links to readme, some people shares thougts and some write sql to help. I don't think taht write sql statement to someone who is stuck is very HUGE thing, but I see that there are angry people also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Title,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Done' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as Done,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Status='Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as Rejected
   FROM [Table] group by Title
```

thanks to

[Sql Server equivalent of a COUNTIF aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582637/sql-server-equivalent-of-a-countif-aggregate-function)

Comment: Thank you, @pm100, you saved me a lot of nerves for tommorow. God bless you.

Comment: Alternatively: `count(*) filter (where status = 'Done')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that doesnt work for me (not using postgres tho)

Comment: Well the question is tagged with Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, but I was curious if this was standard sql or a postgres special

Comment: The `filter()` clause is part of the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried it here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc dont know what engine that is

Comment: Shrug. w3fools is full of errors anyway.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - It was the only sql testbed I had to hand. (like godbolt for testing out code). Can you recommend a better one

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14